# How to load String by BufferedReader?

Tags: java, string, bufferedreader

I need to load in a given String which will be type in as an input String：

```
             20 6
             ....................
             ..XXXXX..XXX.XXX..X.
             ..X.X.X..X.XXX.X..X.
             ..XXXXX..XX.X..X....
             ..XX......XXXXXX..X.
             ....................
```

something like that. It contains 2 integers and a String with "." and "X"
Now I just want to ask 2 questions:
1)I need to load the 2 integers first,but how can get the first two integers by BufferedReader?(the 2 int is divide by space between each other and the rest)

2)Then after loading the two integers,how can I load the following rest string char by char?(Like everytime I need to just load one char,then I go to some function,then come back and load the next char;and between there is no blank space)

Here is part of my code:

```
       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
       String str=br.readLine();
       number1 = Integer.parseInt();
       number2 = Integer.parseInt();
```

And now I don't know how to continue...Anyone can help me to load it?

Comment: Use `Scanner` instead.

Answer (score 0):

For 1) you just need to do a `split`

```
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
   String str=br.readLine();
   String ints[] = str.split(" ");
   number1 = Integer.parseInt( ints[0] );
   number2 = Integer.parseInt( ints[1] );
```

Then for 2) once you have a String you can have it length and so get them char by char ;)

```
String lol = "......XXX..XX...";
for( int i = 0; i < lol.length(); i++ )
    System.out.println(lol.charAt(i));
```

With this you will get all your string char by char

Answer (score 0):

It is much better if you use `Scanner` then you can read int and the String easier.
I suppose you input two integers as col and row.
Example like this:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int col = scan.nextInt();
int row = scan.nextInt(); //input two int first
scan.nextLine();
for(int i = 0; i < row; i++) { 
    String s = scan.nextLine();
    for(int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
        char c = s.charAt(j);
        //your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: but there are lots of problems about "/n" when I input the data,which is always wrong.How to fix that?

Comment: ignore it by checking for it and dumping it in the loop.

Comment: @user3390163 If you input the string from console and there are "/n", how do you mark the end of your input?

Comment: Can you describe a little more?Because I still don't get it...Thanks!

Comment: @user3390163 I mean if the program doesnt know how many lines you will input and there is no symbol that you have finished the input, the program will always wait for your input. Isn't it?

Comment: @locoyou actually the second number is how many line there is,the first number is how many column there is.But I don't know when I use Scanner ,it not working for load the String after load 2 integers from input...

Comment: @user3390163 What's the problem? `scan.nextLiine()` will read a whole line of your input

Comment: @locoyou I want get the data char by char,which is seems not work for scan.nextLine() .

Comment: @user3390163 OK, I dont know how to get it char by char with Scanner. You may try InputStreamReader. But I wonder its necessity to read data char by char from console. I tried my best :(